# Conteúdo sobrepõe o menu fixo ao rolar a página

Tags: html, css, menu, posicionamento

Já tentei colocar `z-index: 2` no `<header></header>`, mas não funcionou

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  transition: linear 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header>nav * {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

header>nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header>nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

header>nav>ul>li {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

header>nav>ul>li[ng-click]:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header>nav>ul>li>ul {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
}

header>nav>ul>li>ul>li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: none;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>ul>li {
  display: flex;
}

ng-include {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

input[type="submit"],
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

td,
th {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table tr th {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #222;
}

table {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #777;
}

table tr {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

td,
th {
  flex: 1;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 43.125em) {
  th {
    display: none;
  }
  table tr td:before {
    content: attr(title);
    width: 75px;
    display: block;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  table tr {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  table tr td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3em 0 1em 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<body ng-controller="controllerDataPOA as controller" class="ng-scope">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>UFEF</li>
        <li>Usuários
          <ul>
            <li>Conectar</li>
            <li>Cadastrar</li>
            <li>Meu perfil</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div>
    <h1>5 universidades, faculdades, escolas estaduais e federais cadastradas</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Endereço</th>
          <th>Bairro</th>
          <th>Telefone</th>
          <th>Site/Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>COLÉGIO DE APLICAÇÃO DA UFRGS</td>
          <td>AV. BENTO GONÇALVES, 9500 </td>
          <td>AGRONOMIA</td>
          <td>3308-6977 </td>
          <td>edson@cap.ufrgs.br</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ESCOLA TÉCNICA DA UFRGS</td>
          <td>RUA CORONEL VICENTE, 281 </td>
          <td>CENTRO</td>
          <td>3930-6010 </td>
          <td>gabinete@poa.ifrs.edu.br</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>COLÉGIO MILITAR DE PORTO ALEGRE</td>
          <td>AV. JOSÉ BONIFÁCIO, 363 </td>
          <td>FARROUPILHA</td>
          <td>3226-4209 </td>
          <td>cmpa@cmpa.tche.br</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CRECHE FRANCESCA ZACARO FARACO</td>
          <td>RUA SAO MANOEL, SN° </td>
          <td>RIO BRANCO</td>
          <td>3316-5273 </td>
          <td>creche@ufrgs.br</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>INSTITUTO FEDERAL EDUCAÇÃO E TECNOLOGIA DO RS - CAMPUS RESTINGA</td>
          <td>ESTRADA JOÃO ANTÔNIO DA SILVEIRA, 351 </td>
          <td>RESTINGA</td>
          <td>3247-8400 </td>
          <td>comunicacao@restinga.ifrs.edu.br</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guilherme o seu conteúdo já está por traz do `header`, o problema é que o `header` não tem Cor de background, ai fica parecendo que um está por cima do outro, mas não está!

Veja o exemplo, só coloquei uma cor no `headere` e já resolveu. Também precisei fazer uma classe na `div` que engloba a tabela pq no responsivo ainda estava com problema.

```css
    body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  transition: linear 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: red;
  z-index:1000;
}

header>nav * {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

header>nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header>nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

header>nav>ul>li {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

header>nav>ul>li[ng-click]:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header>nav>ul>li>ul {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
}

header>nav>ul>li>ul>li {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: none;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>ul>li {
  display: flex;
}

ng-include {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

input[type="submit"],
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

td,
th {
  overflow: hidden;
}

table tr th {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #222;
}

table {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #777;
}

table tr {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

td,
th {
  flex: 1;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 43.125em) {
  th {
    display: none;
  }
  table tr td:before {
    content: attr(title);
    width: 75px;
    display: block;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  table tr {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  table tr td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3em 0 1em 1em;
  }
  .respos {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body ng-controller="controllerDataPOA as controller" class="ng-scope">
        <header>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>UFEF</li>
              <li>Usuários
                <ul>
                  <li>Conectar</li>
                  <li>Cadastrar</li>
                  <li>Meu perfil</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="respo">
          <h1>5 universidades, faculdades, escolas estaduais e federais cadastradas</h1>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Bairro</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Site/Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>COLÉGIO DE APLICAÇÃO DA UFRGS</td>
                <td>AV. BENTO GONÇALVES, 9500 </td>
                <td>AGRONOMIA</td>
                <td>3308-6977 </td>
                <td>edson@cap.ufrgs.br</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ESCOLA TÉCNICA DA UFRGS</td>
                <td>RUA CORONEL VICENTE, 281 </td>
                <td>CENTRO</td>
                <td>3930-6010 </td>
                <td>gabinete@poa.ifrs.edu.br</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>COLÉGIO MILITAR DE PORTO ALEGRE</td>
                <td>AV. JOSÉ BONIFÁCIO, 363 </td>
                <td>FARROUPILHA</td>
                <td>3226-4209 </td>
                <td>cmpa@cmpa.tche.br</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>CRECHE FRANCESCA ZACARO FARACO</td>
                <td>RUA SAO MANOEL, SN° </td>
                <td>RIO BRANCO</td>
                <td>3316-5273 </td>
                <td>creche@ufrgs.br</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>INSTITUTO FEDERAL EDUCAÇÃO E TECNOLOGIA DO RS - CAMPUS RESTINGA</td>
                <td>ESTRADA JOÃO ANTÔNIO DA SILVEIRA, 351 </td>
                <td>RESTINGA</td>
                <td>3247-8400 </td>
                <td>comunicacao@restinga.ifrs.edu.br</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: Mancada minha, é que parecia que o texto do menu estava por baixo, mas enfim, valeu

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam cara se eu te falar que eu fiquei uns 20 mim olhando para a tela sem entender pq estava por cima vc acredita. Quando caiu a ficha que era a cor eu até dei rizada aqui :D